# Can not register Angular controller

Tags: angularjs, json

I know that there are dozens of the same topics, but I can't find the answer.

I created a simple table, filled it with data from JSON, but it is not loading and I have this error:

> The controller with the name 'TableDataController' is not registered.

```
<div class = "customtable" style="overflow:auto;" ng-style="{height:position.height+'px', width:position.width+'px'}">
<div ng-app="TableFill" ng-controller="TableDataController">
    <table style="table-layout: fixed;">
        <thead class="customtable-title">
            <tr>
                <th class="customtable-title-cell">Время погрузки</th>
                <th class="customtable-title-cell">Назначение</th>
                <th class="customtable-title-cell">Расчётное качество</th>
                <th class="customtable-title-cell">Качество по ЯФО</th>
                <th class="customtable-title-cell">Отклонение от планового</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="customtable-grid-row" ng-repeat="load in loadingTimes">
                <td>{{load.loadingTime}}</td>
                <td>{{load.target}}</td>
                <td>{{load.quality}}</td>
                <td>{{load.yafo}}</td>
                <td>{{load.deviation}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module("TableFill", []);
app.controller('TableDataController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.loadingTimes = [                
        { 'loadingTime': '001', 'target': 'Alpha', 'quality': 37, 'yafo': 37, 'deviation': 37 },
        { 'loadingTime': '002', 'target': 'Bravo', 'quality': 27, 'yafo': 37, 'deviation': 37 },
        { 'loadingTime': '003', 'target': 'Charlie', 'quality': 29, 'yafo': 37, 'deviation': 37 },
        { 'loadingTime': '004', 'target': 'Delta', 'quality': 19, 'yafo': 37, 'deviation': 37 },
        { 'loadingTime': '005', 'target': 'Echo', 'quality': 32, 'yafo': 37, 'deviation': 37 }];           
} );
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a working example: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hhgEwxdEEJv3gheZZv06?p=preview). There is nothing wrong with your current code. Are you not showing your entire code?

Comment: your requirement isn't clear and current posted code is working fine

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Yes, I do not put full JS file, cause it is a huge system and it is not possible to include full html file here.
I see, that all works fine alone, then I will try to find problem in entire code.
thanks.

Comment: It's most likely that the issue is in `var app = angular.module("TableFill", []);` 
`app.controller('TableDataController', ...)`. If it's written somehow differently in your JS code, I would look at it first (or post what you have here)

Answer (score 0):

you should fix your script code
 from

```
app.controller('TableDataController', function ($scope){ ... code ...} );
```

to

```
app.controller('TableDataController',['$scope', function ($scope) {...code..}]);
```